# What is the best way to loop over an array in JsonValue in libgdx?

Tags: java, json, libgdx

I am porting an Android-only Game to libgdx. The world and level info is stored in a json file.

I used to do access the array with getJSONArray(id) like this:

```
public static WorldVO create(JSONObject worldObject) {
    WorldVO worldVO = new WorldVO();

    worldVO.id = worldObject.getInt("id");
    worldVO.unlock = worldObject.getInt("stars_to_unlock");

    worldObject.getChild("levels");
    JSONArray levelJsonArray = worldObject.getJSONArray("levels");
    int len = levelJsonArray.length();
    worldVO.levelVOs = new LevelVO[len];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        worldVO.levelVOs[i] = LevelVO.create(levelJsonArray.getJSONObject(i));
    }
```

...

which worked fine but I cannot find the correct way to loop through the "levels" child of the "worldObect" Json in libgdx when i use **JsonValue** instead of **JSONObject**.

Accessing the integer fields is not a problem but JsonValue does not have a getJSONArray. Any idea what to use? Thanks!

Comment: Why using JsonValue ? JsonValue is an Interface which does not possess the needed methods

Comment: I am trying to use the libdx classes for parsing JSON, what should I use to parse?

Comment: The above code, which is fine,  does not work with libdx ?

Comment: The libgdx wiki https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Reading-%26-writing-JSON says to use JsonReader to read the file into JsonValue objects. The JSONObject class is part of the android-sdk and not included in the ligbdx engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this : http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/JsonValue.html
Try this :

```
public static WorldVO create(JsonValue worldObject)
{
    WorldVO worldVO = new WorldVO();

    worldVO.id = worldObject.getInt("id");
    worldVO.unlock = worldObject.getInt("stars_to_unlock");

    JsonValue levels = worldObject.get("levels");
    int len = levels.size;
    worldVO.levelVOs = new LevelVO[len];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        worldVO.levelVOs[i] = LevelVO.create(levels.get(i));
    }
```

Comment: looks good, i was onto the same thing, i have to be offline for a few hours but will accept this if it works out, thanks!

Comment: Tell me if it does not work, we'll try to figure it out

Comment: thanks, simply using get(i) to have a JsonValue to loop over seems to be the way to go

Comment: Indeed, I used the wrong method, I edited my response